# how to get different return value from display text with Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

```
public void onNetworkSuccess(List<Mission> missionList) {

            List<LocationSpinnerObject> LocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            LocationsList.add(getCurrentLocation());
            for(Mission mission : missionList){



            }
            LocationsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

            });
```

I want to display from my mission object just few data as lang, lat and  address. In the spinner I wanna show the address and when I choose one of the address the map animation will be updated to this location (with means lat and lang will be the returns values)

how can I do it ?
thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to fill spinner data from Mission list with lang, lat, address?

Comment: to add the spinner with address but when I select one of the address the return value is lat and lang so I will be able to update the map on my activity

Comment: @MimiBen-DavidElgrabli Can you show us your `Mission` object?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that your `Mission` object contains `lat`, `lang`, and `address`

```
public void onNetworkSuccess(List<Mission> missionList) {
    List<String> LocationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    LocationsList.add(getCurrentLocation());
    for(Mission mission : missionList) {
        LocationList.add(mission.getAddress()); // This is will show only the address on the spinner.    
    }

    LocationsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Mission mission = missionList.get(position); // Retrieve your mission with the selected item position.
            float latitude = mission.getLatitude();
            float longitude = mission.getLongitude(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });    
}
```